# Remove HTML tags from txt file

Tags: php, html, content-management-system, ckeditor

I am using a very basic CMS system for a very specific situation: No database is being used, only a folder with a .txt file with PHP posting directly there all the text from a text area. here is the code I am using to do this:

```
$text1 = "../conteudos/start/text1.txt";
if (isset($_POST['body1'])) {
    $newData = nl2br(htmlspecialchars($_POST['body1']));
    $handle = fopen($text1, "w");
    fwrite($handle, $newData);
    fclose($handle);
}
// ------------------------------------------------
if (file_exists($text1)) {

    $myData1 = file_get_contents($text1);
}
```

And to display it:

```
$text1 = "conteudos/start/text1.txt";
if (file_exists($text1)) {

    $myData1 = file_get_contents($text1);
}
```

All works great, but when I install CKeditdor html tags are all over the place... How do I take them out?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `strip_tags()` to remove HTML tags:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

```
$myData = file_get_contents($text1);
$myData = strip_tags($myData);
```

Also, when saving the file, you should not be doing `htmlspecialchars()` since this will encode characters such as < and > with & gt; and & lt;

I'd recommend removing this line.

Comment: Nice try but it's not working... I don't get this problem though if I am using a database (past experiences), wonder if it is because I am using a txt file...

Comment: It shouldn't make a difference where you get it from. It works on a string. I've just noticed that when you're saving the data to the file you're doing `htmlspecialchars()` which will encode the HTML tag characters i.e. < and > as &gt; and &lt; which means when you read from the file, these tags won't actually exist so strip_tags() is essentially doing nothing. Try removing `htmlspecialchars()`

Comment: Nope... still not working... Can't believe I will have to make a database for such a simple system... Thanks for the help anyway!

Comment: What is actually happening now? You shouldn't need to, a database is just another way of storing data. Up to you though.

Comment: Nothing is happening, that is the issue... I did remove the htmlspecialchars() like you said...

Comment: I'm truly sorry, apparently I was having an issue with my code. I tried again from scratch and it did work! Thanks to both of you!

Comment: I don't know if I should make a new question out of this, but I have another issue: I am echoing the data into text areas (for edition purpose) using the "<?php echo str_replace("<br />","",$myData1); ?>", but it's not working, <br> are simply not appearing... even if I take the str_replace out... any suggestions?